# How can Arjuna undergo 'viswa rupa darshan' if he is a part of universe?

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, arjuna

Arjuna undergoes 'Vishwa Roopa darshan' (realizing cosmic form) of Krishna in [Chapter 11: Viśhwarūp Darśhan Yog](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/11) of Bagavath Geetha with the grace of Krishna.

> There **Arjun could see** the totality of the entire universe established
> in one place, in that body of the God of gods.
>
> [[13]](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/11/verse/13)

Since it cannot be seen through normal eyes, Krishna granted [divine vision to Arjuna](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/11/verse/8).

It is well-known that a jivan muktha ceases to exist individually and becomes united with Brahman. It is the ultimate state. Viswa Roopa darshan is not ultimate but the experience of being nearer to such an ultimate state.

It is evident that arjuna is part of the universe, then how can he see the Viswaroopam without merging into it? It seems from the chapter that Arjuna still has his own identity during the darshan. How is it possible? How does Arjuna still have his own individual identity while undergoing Vishwa Roopa darshan?

Comment: I think it is the state of mind. The state of mind has to be in a state of nirvikalpa (thought-less) to experience the oneness.

Answer (score 3):

An individual ego cannot experience the non-dual Brahman, referred to as Nirguna Brahman, where the ego vanishes. Arjuna experienced the vision of Iswara, Saguna Brahman. Remember that Saguna Brahman, Iswara, is how individuals within Maya experience, or perceive, Brahman. Iswara is described with all the attributes which Arjuna experiences in his vision.

For reference see Ramanuja's commentary Sri Bhyasa on Brahma Sutras III.ii.11 and Svetasvatara Upanishad III.1-3, III.17, VI.6-8, IV.11, IV.13, IV.17, Kaushitaki Upanishad IV.3 and 8, Brhadarnayaka Upanishad III.viii.9

Answer (score 1):

Obviously Arjuna would not be able to see the entire universe through his physical eyes since he is himself part of the universe. This is the reason why he was given the power of divine vision, i.e. he saw everything the way God sees it.

> You cannot have an experience of Me merely with your physical eye. I
> therefore give you **the power of divine vision**. Behold with that My
> power as the Lord of all.

**Gita 11.8**